# How to use the --tmpfs mount in the Kubernetes YAML file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to use the --tmpfs flag from the docker run command in the Kubernetes YAML file but could not find the way.

```
sudo docker run --name=ubuntu-gnome -d --rm \
  --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock --tmpfs /tmp \
  --cap-add SYS_BOOT --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
  -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup \
  -p 5901:5901 -p 6901:6901 \
  darkdragon001/ubuntu-gnome-vnc
```

Comment: (Note that a reasonably-configured Kubernetes cluster will probably prevent you from claiming a `SYS_ADMIN` Linux capability or mounting the host's `/sys` directory.  If you need a full GNOME desktop environment, a virtual machine might be a better match.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for an emptyDir volume, such as the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp
      name: tmp
      subPath: tmp
    - mountPath: /run
      name: tmp
      subPath: run
    - mountPath: /run/lock
      name: tmp
      subPath: run-lock
  volumes:
  - name: tmp
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
      sizeLimit: 64Mi
```